# including image files in classpath

Tags: tomcat

I'm deploying a tomcat web application which reads certain  files like the image files, app properties file, etc. to get the values for the application.

However, I do not want to place this in the war (since this war is common to multiple instances) and keep it under conf/.

Will adding conf to shared.loader in catalina.properties work? How do I check if it worked?

In the Java src I'm using getPropertiesFromClasspath to read the properties file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, adding the path of the required resources to the shared loader (or common.loader) in catalina.properties is the solution you require. In terms of checking if it works, you will know at server runtime whether or not you have correctly added the write classpath. Other than that, there isn't much you can do.

The following paragraph about the syntax is taken from the website: http://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-classpath

- To add a folder as a class repository, use the format "path/to/foldername"
- To add all JARs in a folder as class repositories, use the format: "path/to/foldername/*.jar"
- To add a single JAR file as a class repository, use the following format: "file://path/to/foldername/jarname.jar"
- To call environment variables, use the ${} format, i.e. ${VARIABLE_NAME}
- To declare multiple resources, separate each entry with a comma.
  All paths may be relative to CATALINA_BASE or CATALINA_HOME, or absolute.

Comment: The website mentions under this section to use a shared.loader property when we want to multiple applications to share a lib. 
(see Problem: I want multiple applications to share a single JAR file, and I want this JAR files to reside within Tomcat.)

My use case is that I just want the image files for a single application to be picked up. So I could also add the conf directory to the common.loader property right?

Comment: yeah that will be fine too.